# How to install OpenGL arm64 libraries on amd64 for cross compiling

Tags: cross-compiling

I want to cross-compile an executable for an arm64 target on an Ubuntu 20.04 amd64 host. The program needs to be linked to the OpenGL libraries, so I need to install the arm64 OpenGL library versions on the host.

I have added the

> deb [arch=aarch64,arm64] http://ch.ports.ubuntu.com/ focal main
> restricted

to the /etc/apt/sources.list, but I still cannot install the libraries:

```
> $ sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev:arm64 
> Reading package lists...
> Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
> been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to
> resolve the situation:
> 
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  mesa-common-dev:arm64
> : Depends: libgl-dev:arm64 but it is not going to be installed
>                          Depends: libglx-dev:arm64 but it is not going to be installed 
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
> packages.
```

I can query for the needed arm64 library:

```
$ apt policy mesa-common-dev:arm64
mesa-common-dev:arm64:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 20.0.4-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
     20.0.4-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ch.ports.ubuntu.com focal/main arm64 Packages
```

But that's it.

Any idea how to make this work? Should I just manually copy the libraries from the target to the host?